# Are there any multi-host container orchestration tools which allow USB device mapping? Or any production grade solutions/hacks?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, usb, docker-swarm

Docker provides a --device flag for individual containers to map device ports (USB devices for example; ttyUSB0, ttyACM0) at run-time.

This feature is great but seems to disappear when we abstract away from the host machine if using Docker swarm or Kubernetes however, I have not been able to confirm if this feature doesn't exist (I would be surprised if such a feature did exist since these orchestration tools implement a high degree of abstraction). Being said, I absolutely need to utilize the power of an orchestration tool but at the same time in spite of abstraction, I also require the ability to map device ports because I intend to retrieve data from sensors.

Are there any production grade solutions to this problem? or does the feature exist in some manner?

-Thankyou

Comment: The usual model for, say, Kubernetes is that you’ll have dozens (or more) of indistinguishable nodes and it doesn’t matter which one you get scheduled on.  Accessing some random node’s USB devices isn’t generally useful.  Avoiding Docker entirely (a design goal is to hide hardware devices) and using an automation tool like Chef or Ansible might be a better match for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one community proposal for this topic ([in multi-node env you can consider using NFS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785628/adding-database-to-raspberry-pi-kubernetes-cluster/55790061#55790061))

Hi I am not expert in this matter but it seems like it's the task for IOT.
You should consider using IOT like more general solution while working with sensors:

- [Overview of Internet of Things](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/iot-overview)
- [iot-edge-virtual-kubelet-provider](https://github.com/azure/iot-edge-virtual-kubelet-provider)
- [Device Plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/device-plugins/)
- [Google Cloud IoT-ready hardware](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/iot/kit/)
- [Using K3S workers nodes on ARM](https://dev.to/david_j_eddy/intro-k3s-a-less-needy-kubernetes-3e53)

Hope this help